# In a Connected Weighted Graph G, if T1 and T2 are two spanning trees that have the MST property, then they have the same total weight.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I am trying to prove the above statement. This Lemma popped up when I am studying Prim's Algorithm.

The proof given in the book (Baase & Van Gelder P392) is by Induction:

Let $k$ be the number of edges in $T1$ but not in $T2$ (and Vice Versa).

> Base Case: $k=0$, $T1 = T2$, hence they have the same weight.

> Inductive Step: For $k>0$, Assume the Lemma holds when there are $j$ differing edges where $0 < j < k$. Let $uv$ be the minimum weight edge among the differing edges (assume $uv$ in $T2$).

> Look at the unique path in T1 from $u$ to $v$. Suppose that it is made up of $w0$...$wp$ where $w0 = u, wp  = v$. This path must contain some edge different from T2.

This is part of the proof only, but I am currently stuck at the last statement where "This path must contain...".

I'm thinking in the direction where if T2 does not have different edges, then it contains this path. But I still find it hard to wrap my head around about how does it connect to the proof.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As far as I understand, you say that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both minimum spanning trees. This implies they have the same total weight, otherwise, one of them would have greater total weight than the other, and so it cannot be an MST

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat standard argument involving edges which are not in trees. By assumption you have $uv$ in $T_2$. The unique path $p$ in $T_1$, which connects $u$ and $v$ does not contain $uv$ by assumption. So if this whole path $p$ was contained in $T_2$, you'd have two different paths in $T_2$ connecting $u$ and $v$, namely the single edge $uv$ and the path $p$.

But that means that $T_2$ contains a circle, which contradicts $T_2$ being a tree. Hence not all of $p$ can be contained in $T_2$, thus there must exist some edge in $p$ which is not in $T_2$.